# Why is my Laravel Model new model I made has database connection null and table?

Tags: eloquent, laravel-10

Made a database to contain a single page worth of content but then I'm trying to display the data no data being shown when ii check with dd there's no database connection and table.
The migration is already run, and I put data on the database.

Here is the  {{ dd($end) }} that have null on both database connection and table
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAEDX.jpg)

Here is the {{ dd($blog) }} that has mysql and at table
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iUAR.png)

Here are the Web routes.

```
  Route::get('/end-to-end', [EndController::class, 'view']);
```

Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\End;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class EndController extends Controller
{
    public function view(End $end)
    {
        return view('static_edit.end-to-end', ['end' => $end]);
    }


    public function update(Request $request, End $end)
    {
        $formFields = $request->validate([
            'header' => 'required',
            'sub_header' => 'required',
            'header_para' => 'required',
            'header_img' => 'required',
            'header_card' => 'required',
            'card_svg1' => 'required',
            'card_svg2' => 'required',
            'card_svg3' => 'required',
            'card_h1' => 'required',
            'card_h2' => 'required',
            'card_h3' => 'required',
            'card_para1' => 'required',
            'card_para2' => 'required',
            'card_para3' => 'required',
            'steps_header' => 'required',
            'steps_h1' => 'required',
            'steps_h2' => 'required',
            'steps_h3' => 'required',
            'steps_h4' => 'required',
            'steps_h5' => 'required',
            'steps_h6' => 'required',
            'steps_h7' => 'required',
            'steps_h8' => 'required',
            'steps_para1' => 'required',
            'steps_para2' => 'required',
            'steps_para3' => 'required',
            'steps_para4' => 'required',
            'steps_para5' => 'required',
            'steps_para6' => 'required',
            'steps_para7' => 'required',
            'steps_para8' => 'required',
            'steps_img1' => 'required',
            'steps_img2' => 'required',
            'steps_img3' => 'required',
            'steps_img4' => 'required',
            'steps_img5' => 'required',
            'steps_img6' => 'required',
            'steps_img7' => 'required',
            'steps_img8' => 'required'
        ]);
        $end->update($formFields);
    }
}
```

Model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;

class End extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    public $casts = [
        'header',
        'sub_header',
        'header_para',
        'header_img',
        'header_card',
        'card_svg1',
        'card_svg2',
        'card_svg3',
        'card_h1',
        'card_h2',
        'card_h3',
        'card_para1',
        'card_para2',
        'card_para3',
        'steps_header',
        'steps_h1',
        'steps_h2',
        'steps_h3',
        'steps_h4',
        'steps_h5',
        'steps_h6',
        'steps_h7',
        'steps_h8',
        'steps_para1',
        'steps_para2',
        'steps_para3',
        'steps_para4',
        'steps_para5',
        'steps_para6',
        'steps_para7',
        'steps_para8',
        'steps_img1',
        'steps_img2',
        'steps_img3',
        'steps_img4',
        'steps_img5',
        'steps_img6',
        'steps_img7',
        'steps_img8',
    ];
}
```

Migration

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     */
    public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('ends', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('header');
            $table->string('sub_header');
            $table->text('header_para');
            $table->binary('header_img');
            $table->string('header_card');
            $table->binary('card_svg1');
            $table->binary('card_svg2');
            $table->binary('card_svg3');
            $table->string('card_h1');
            $table->string('card_h2');
            $table->string('card_h3');
            $table->text('card_para1');
            $table->text('card_para2');
            $table->text('card_para3');
            $table->string('steps_header');
            $table->string('steps_h1');
            $table->string('steps_h2');
            $table->string('steps_h3');
            $table->string('steps_h4');
            $table->string('steps_h5');
            $table->string('steps_h6');
            $table->string('steps_h7');
            $table->string('steps_h8');
            $table->text('steps_para1');
            $table->text('steps_para2');
            $table->text('steps_para3');
            $table->text('steps_para4');
            $table->text('steps_para5');
            $table->text('steps_para6');
            $table->text('steps_para7');
            $table->text('steps_para8');
            $table->binary('steps_img1');
            $table->binary('steps_img2');
            $table->binary('steps_img3');
            $table->binary('steps_img4');
            $table->binary('steps_img5');
            $table->binary('steps_img6');
            $table->binary('steps_img7');
            $table->binary('steps_img8');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     */
    public function down(): void
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('ends');
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing `$end` to the view function anywhere therefore it is always null.

Comment: I did try putting it with route model binding but it just resulted in 404 not found